# Referencing a definition name in flex

Tags: regex, tokenize, flex-lexer

Is there a way in flex to reference definition names in the action part of a matched pattern, similar to how you reference to the pattern itself? I would like something similar to

```
%{
#include<stdio.h> 
}%

DIGIT [0-9]

%%

{DIGIT} printf("%s is a %s", yytext, yydefinition)

%%

int main(){

yylex(); return 0; 
}
```

I can imagine that the problem with this might be when you have multiple definitions in a rule such as `{DIGIT} | {STRING}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: `lex` (and `flex`) compile the contents of named patterns into tables without providing a way to refer to their names in the lexer.

There is not a lot of help with *states* (aka *start conditions*). lex/flex simply generate `#define` statements for those names.

`flex` has a *debug* switch, but the generated tables for that still do not include the information you want.

`yacc` and `bison`, on the other hand, have tables which can be used to help with error messages.  The [`cproto`](http://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html) program uses that feature, adjusting for several variations of `yacc` and `bison`.

Comment: Thanks for te info, an alternative I can think of is if patterns in the definitions could be defined in terms of a string variable previously defined in the `%{ ... }%` then this variable could be referenced in the action? is something like this possible? example:

Comment: I don't see that it could: lex/flex only check *syntax* of the chunks of C, enough to match curly braces, for example.  They do not pay attention to *definitions* in the C code.